# Gulp replace occurrences of reved/renamed files in javascript

Tags: node.js, gulp

My file structure looks something like this:

```
src/js/core.js
src/js/lazyloadme.js
```

My gulp process outputs the following after using gulp-rev and gulp-rename:

```
dist/js/core-f9aj9sw.min.js
dist/js/lazyloadme-h2a39sg.min.js
```

In core.js I have references to lazyloadme.js since I need to lazy load it, but this won't work since the file gets renamed.
How would I search core.js for references to lazyloadme.js and replace it with the new filename with gulp?

Comment: That looks promising: https://github.com/jamesknelson/gulp-rev-replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Gulp-rev-replace](https://github.com/jamesknelson/gulp-rev-replace) seems to work nicely.

For example `lazyloadme.js` gets replaced with `lazyloadme-2a3f573b.min.js`.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var rev = require('gulp-rev');
var revReplace = require('gulp-rev-replace');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('default', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/js/*.js')
        .pipe(rev())
        .pipe(rename(function(file) {
            file.extname = '.min.js';
        }))
        .pipe(revReplace())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));
});
```